# PHP Auto Reply Using HTML Markup

Tags: php, email, html-email

I've got the following code which works perfectly when I don't include the HTML markup headers required to send HTML data. However, as soon as I include the headers necessary for the HTML markup language to be read, the form doesn't auto respond.

Here's my code:

```
   $mail_to = 'test@bookings.com';

$subject = 'Student Booking';
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($field_email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($field_email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$body_message = '<html><body style="font-family:calibri,sans-serif; font-size:18px">';
$body_message .= '<h2 style="font-weight:600; font-size:27px; border-bottom:dashed 1px #CCC; padding-bottom:10px;">Student Booking</h2>';
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Full Name:</strong> '.$field_name."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Age:</strong> '.$field_age."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">E-mail Address:</strong> '.$field_email."</p>\n"."\n";
$body_message .= '</body></html>';

$autoTo = "$field_email";

$subject_auto = 'Booking Received!';
$headers_auto = "From: " . strip_tags('test@bookings.com') . "\r\n";
$headers_auto .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags('test@bookings.com') . "\r\n";
$headers_auto .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers_auto .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$auto_message = '<html><body style="font-family:calibri,sans-serif; font-size:18px">';
$auto_message .= '<h2 style="font-weight:600; font-size:27px; border-bottom:dashed 1px #CCC; padding-bottom:10px;">Student Booking</h2>';
$auto_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Full Name:</strong> '.$field_name."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Age:</strong> '.$field_age."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">E-mail Address:</strong> '.$field_email."</p>\n"."\n";
$auto_message .= '</body></html>';


mail($autoTo, $subject_auto, $headers_auto, "Booking Received!", $auto_message, 'From: test@bookings.com');

mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

Any ideas as to what's wrong with the code? I've tried everything!

Comment: Do you mean that your email won't send? ("form autorespond" isn't really a technical term) Do you know where and how it's failing? And side note: you obviously haven't tried *everything*, or you'd have found the solution already. hehe

Comment: Your call to mail() has bad parameters. It should be:

mail($autoTo, $subject_auto, $auto_message, $headers_auto, 'From: test@bookings.com');

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: As I said the form auto-replies perfectly without the "headers_auto".